# when we click on exit application tag on menu bar of MDIParent1

Tags: vb.net

when we click on exit application tag on menu bar of MDIParent1 then should be show message box yes no if i click on yes then application closed and if i click no then application should be not close and form still alive which was open

```
Private Sub ExitApplicaionToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitApplicaionToolStripMenuItem.Click

    MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

        Application.Exit()

    Else

        'Focus remain on targeted form which is open that time

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for telling us this. Your question, however, is missing a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The show-method [returns the dialogresult:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cked7698(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
    Application.Exit()
End If
```